# Ionic Push Android push notification returning "undefined" message

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

I've been trying to get Android push notifications working for my app for a little while now (iOS already completed) and have everything sorted out besides just getting the notification to actually show up on the Android device.

Registering the device id's, and pushing to the GCM server all seem to be working fine, but when I test what the message in the response back from GCM is returning I keep getting `undefined`.

All responses when pushing the message to GCM are success, correct device id's, a message id associated with it etc. Anyone able to point me in the right direction? Below you will see the code snippet with just a sample "alert" being used to display what is coming back that will end up being used as the notification in the "push".

This alert

```
alert('message = ' + e.message + ' payload message: ' + e.payload.message +
       ' e payload msgcnt: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + ' e.msg: ' + e.msg);
```

doesn't seem to be getting anything back to display the push.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log('deviceready');
    try {
        pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' || device.platform == 'amazon-fireos') {
            console.log('PN register');
            pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {
                "senderID": "177718756870",
                "ecb": "onNotification"
            });     // required!
            console.log('after PN register');

        } else {
            console.log('PN register');
            pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {
                "badge": "true",
                "sound": "true",
                "alert": "true",
                "ecb": "onNotificationAPN"
            }); // required!
            console.log('after PN register');
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        txt = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
        txt += "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
        console.log("ERROR", txt);

    }

}

var pushNotification;

// handle GCM notifications for Android
window.onNotification = function(e) {

    console.log('EVENT RECEIVED ' + e.event)
    console.log("regID BEFORE CHECKS = " + e.regid);

    switch( e.event )
    {

        case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0)
            {
                console.log("regID = " + e.regid);

                var data =
                {
                    'device_id': e.regid,
                    'platform': device.platform,
                    'os_version': device.version,
                    'app_version': lawnmowerConfig.versionString,
                    'device_model': device.model
                };

                localStorage.setItem('push_data', JSON.stringify(data));
            }
            break;

       case 'message':
           console.log('Inside case message: ' + e.regid)

           if (e.foreground)
           {
               // Add something to play a sound once working
           }
           else
           {    
                if (e.coldstart) {
                    console.log("coldstart");

                }
                else {

                    console.log("not coldstart");

                }
           }

           alert('message = ' + e.message + ' payload message: ' + e.payload.message + ' e payload msgcnt: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + ' e.msg: ' + e.msg);

           break;

           case 'error':
                alert('GCM error = ' + e.msg);

           break;

           default:
                // Testing using these alerts instead
                alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');

           break;
    }
};

function tokenHandler (result) {
    console.log('push token handler');
    console.log(result);
    var data =
    {
        'device_id': result,
        'platform': device.platform,
        'os_version': device.version,
        'app_version': lawnmowerConfig.versionString,
        'device_model': device.model
    };
    localStorage.setItem('push_data', JSON.stringify(data));
}

function successHandler (result) {

    console.log('success handler push success');
    console.log("result: " + result);
}

function errorHandler (error) {
    console.log('push error');
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Registering the device id's, and pushing to the GCM server all seem to be working fine, but when I test what the message in the response back from GCM is returning I keep getting `undefined`.

It means that when you are testing "what the message .... is" you are referencing a variable not yet defined. In this line:

```
alert('message = ' + e.message + ' payload message: ' + e.payload.message +
      ' e payload msgcnt: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + ' e.msg: ' + e.msg);
```

there is no variable `e.message`. The data that you send from your server is attached to `e.payload` and value of `e.event` is set to `message`. I think your problem can be solved if you remove `e.message`. Something like:

```
alert('event = ' + e.event + ' payload message: ' + e.payload.message +
      ' e payload msgcnt: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + ' e.msg: ' + e.msg);
```

**Note** To detect variable issues (scope and/or declaration), debug one variable at a time. This will help you to precisely identify a problem and trace it to its origin.

I would advise you to use

```
alert("Payload message: " + e.payload.message);
```